# Python Multiple Inheritance: Argument passing (**kwargs) and super()

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to understand Python multiple inheritance and I kind of understand MRO, super() and passing arguments in MI, but while I was reading the below example it kind of confused me.

```
class Contact:
    all_contacts = []

    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.all_contacts.append(self)


class AddressHolder:
    def __init__(self, street=None, city=None, state=None, code=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.code = code


class Friend(Contact, AddressHolder):
    def __init__(self, phone='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.phone = phone
```

Now what I fail to understand is why use super() in Contact and AddressHolder class. I mean super() is used when we are inheriting from a parent class but both Contact & AddressHolder are not inheriting from any other class. (technically they are inheriting from `object`). This example confuses me with the right use of super()

Comment: afaik it calls the next item in the MRO stack ....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All (new style) classes have a linearized method resolution order (MRO).  Depending on the inheritance tree, actually figuring out the MRO can be a bit mind-bending, but it is deterministic via a [relatively simple algorithm](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). You can also check the MRO through a class's `__mro__` attribute.

`super` gets a delegator to the next class in the MRO.  In your example, `Friend` has the following MRO:

```
Friend -> Contact -> AddressHolder -> object
```

If you call super in one of `Friend`'s methods, you'll get a delegator that delegates to `Contact`'s methods.  If that method doesn't call `super`, you'll never call the methods on `AddressHolder`.  In other words, `super` is responsible for calling only the next method in the MRO, not **ALL** the remaining methods in the MRO.

(If you call `super` in one of `Friend`'s methods and `Contact` doesn't have its own implementation of that method, then `super` will delegate to `AddressHolder`, or whichever class has the next implementation for that method in the MRO.)

---

This is all well and good since `object` has a completely functional `__init__` method (so long as `**kwargs` is empty at that point).  Unfortunately, it doesn't work if you are trying to resolve the call chain of some custom method.  e.g. `foo`.  In that case, you want to insert a base class that all of the base classes inherit from.  Since that class is a base for all of the classes (or at least base classes) to inherit from.  That class will end up at the end of the MRO and can do parameter validation<sup>1</sup>:

```
class FooProvider:
    def foo(self, **kwargs):
        assert not kwargs  # Make sure all kwargs have been stripped

class Bar(FooProvider):
    def foo(self, x, **kwargs):
        self.x = x
        super().foo(**kwargs)

class Baz(FooProvider):
    def foo(self, y, **kwargs):
        self.y = y
        super().foo(**kwargs)

class Qux(Bar, Baz):
    def foo(self, z, **kwargs):
        self.z = z
        super().foo(**kwargs)
```

demo:

```
>>> q = Qux()
>>> q.foo(x=1, y=2, z=3)
>>> vars(q)
{'z': 3, 'y': 2, 'x': 1}
>>> q.foo(die='invalid')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'
>>> 
>>> q.foo(x=1, y=2, z=3, die='invalid')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/google/home/mgilson/sandbox/super_.py", line 18, in foo
    super().foo(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/google/home/mgilson/sandbox/super_.py", line 8, in foo
    super().foo(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/google/home/mgilson/sandbox/super_.py", line 13, in foo
    super().foo(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/google/home/mgilson/sandbox/super_.py", line 3, in foo
    assert not kwargs  # Make sure all kwargs have been stripped
AssertionError
```

Note, you can still have default arguments with this approach so you don't lose too much there.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note, this isn't the only strategy to deal with this problem -- There are other approaches you can take when making mixins, etc. but this is by far the most robust approach.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot @mgilson for such a nice explanation. It makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: downvoted for use of foo, bar, baz etc. instead of descriptive names like parent, son etc.